# Download an older version of a document

Tags: google-drive

I have an Excel sheet document on Google Drive with several revisions. I want to download one of its older versions to my machine.

How can I do this?

*(Google Drive allows downloading the latest version directly from `File > Download as`, and I didn't find any way download the revisions.)*

Answer (score 17):

If you download the current version of your document, right-click on the download in the Downloads window of your browser (Firefox) and copy the URL. Then simply append `&revision=NNN` and paste this new URL into your browser address bar and hit enter. It will download that specific revision.

So the only exercise left is finding out which revision ID you need to use.

In order to do that, visit [developers.google.com revisions list](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list#try-it) and click on *Try it now*, then enter the fileId of your document, which is the long string of characters and numbers between `docs.google.com/document/d/` and the next slash in your browsers URL bar when editing the document. It's also visible in the download URL you copied before. Paste that into the *fileId* on the API explorer page an hit *Authorize and execute*.

Scroll down to the response, look at the *modifiedTime* and choose the correct number from the *id* field. Then use that number to download your document. The final URL should look something like this:

```
docs.google.com/document/u/0/d/XXXX/export?format=docx&revision=NNN
```

Where `XXXX` is the fileId and `NNN` is your revision number.

---

Comments below indicate people are having trouble with this solution, but it works in Jan 2022 with an updated URL.

Note that the base URL to which the revision is appended will vary over time, and may vary depending on the Google Workspace you're using. As of 2022-01-08, with a basic Google account (@gmail.com), this is the base URL of a download:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=XXXXXX&exportFormat=docx
```

and this is the corresponding URL for download of a specific revision:

```
https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/documents/export/Export?id=XXXXXX&exportFormat=docx&revision=NNNNN
```

See above for instructions on how to get the download URL by downloading the current version of a document, or use the `exportLinks` property returned by a [get on a File resource using the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files) (with fields="*" or fields="exportLinks").

Comment: Upvote this!!! Confirmed working for Google Sheets as well. Do note that the time shown in the JSON response is in GMT, so while the revision history proper shows the time stamps in your local time zone, you need to convert that to GMT before you can find the exact revision.

Comment: @ADTC: a year later doesn't seem to be working. Does it still works for you?

Comment: @Adobe just tried, it works but you may have a hard time finding the correct revision ID from the API. Is that where you're stuck?

Comment: @Adobe maybe this additional trick will help you find the revision ID you want. If you couldn't find the GMT timestamp you were looking for, look for `nextPageToken` at the very top of the JSON response. Put this value into the `pageToken` field and Execute again. This will give you a new JSON response with more revision IDs. Keep doing this until you find the revision ID you want.

Comment: @ADTC: thanks, on the second try I had some kind of success: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/106553/14417. However, I don't seem to have "nextPageToken" at the json response.

Comment: @Adobe you'll only have nextPageToken if there's a next page of results to navigate to. If you didn't see it, you're in the last page or the only page.

Comment: This does not seem to work any more, as @Adobe said, at least for docs. Does anyone have a more recent version of the URL tweak that is necessary to get the pdf of an older version?

Answer (score 9):

- Go to *File* → *See Revision History*
- Select the version you want then click **Restore this version**

This won't delete any versions — you will still be able to go back to the current version.

[The full article can be found here](https://docs.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=190843).

Comment: But this is forcing me to restore to an older version which I don't want because other users are view/editing document at the same time. Any other approach?

Comment: @RameshSoni that's exactly what fhackenberger's answer avoids!

Answer (score 2):

I tried doing what fhackenberger suggested but it didnt work as it retrieved only last few revisions and I wanted almost a month old version.

But I did find a very easy way to download it. When seeing version history, after you select the version you want under version history to the right, click on the options(three vertical dots on the top right corner of the highlighted version) and select "Make a Copy". This downloaded the version i wanted

Comment: This underrated answer is actually a good hint. It can be easier to perform when you have a very heavy file, and every click has a slow response

Answer (score 1):

When you look at the version history, there are 3 dots next to each version.  You can make a copy of a version and save it wherever you want and download.

Answer (score 0):

Using Chrome, I'm able to do this for spreadsheets (but not docs unfortunately) :

1. Go to File > See Revision History
2. Display the revision you want to download
3. UnClick "Show Changes" (if you don't want to see the changes"
4. Right click on your document and select "View Page Source"
5. Remove the view-source: from

this will give you the revision in HTML

Comment: An HTML page? No thanks. I want the proper export.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this `https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/0/d/DID/export?format=xlsx&rev=RID&gid=SID&id=DID`

Where:

- DID - document ID (used twice)
- RID - revision ID
- SID - spreadsheet id (I have spreadsheet with many sheets and needed just one)

[Ziad's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/15213) helped to come to this link.

Answer (score 0):

Automating [fhackenberger's answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/89808/14417):

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'json'
require 'active_support/core_ext/date' # required for timezone calculation; gem install activesupport
# require 'byebug'


# ========
## inputs:

jsonFile       = 'revisions.json' # file with json response obtained from https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/reference/revisions/list#try-it
docId          = 'you doc id' # e.g.: M67keINXrkCAPy9HyGEgyM5Q175yFM8byQeM953alao3
dateStartsWith = 'May 30'
format         = 'xlsx' # xlsx or docx
timezone       = 'Moscow' # list all timezones: ruby -e "require 'active_support/core_ext/date'; puts ActiveSupport::TimeZone.all.map(&:name)"


# =========
## program:

jsonString = File.read(jsonFile)
jsonData   = JSON.parse(jsonString)

# add local time stamps:
jsonData['revisions'].each { |rev| rev["localTimeStamp"] = Time.parse(rev["modifiedTime"]).in_time_zone(timezone).strftime("%b %e, %k:%M:%S %p, %Y") }

if format == 'xlsx'
  type = 'spreadsheets'
else
  format = 'docx'
  type = 'document'
end

revs = jsonData['revisions'].select {|rev| rev["localTimeStamp"].start_with?(dateStartsWith) }.each { |rev| rev["link"] = "https://docs.google.com/#{type}/u/0/d/#{docId}/export?format=#{format}&revision=#{rev['id']}" }

puts JSON.pretty_generate(revs)
```

Still somehow I get only some revisions, not all of them.